# Retrieve extra info from one option from autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I finally managed to retrieve a list from the available options related to the name searched from a field. Now, my goal is to retrieve some extra info when the user selects a specific option from the list. The JSON returns only the last name of the person and the user id which is an auto-increment field in the database. So I thought that I could send another JSON request to the server to actually return all the information available from the person specified from the user id. Is this considered bad practice ? Is there something alternative I am maybe missing ?
All in all, my code is here:

```
        <script>    
    $(function() {   
        $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
              delay: 0,
              minLength: 2,           
              source: function(request, response) {
              $.ajax({
              url: 'search.php', 
              data: { term: request.term }, 
              success: function(data) {  
                       data = JSON.parse(data);
                       response($.map(data, function(item) {
                       return {
                              label: item.firstName,
                              value: item.firstName};
                            }));
              }
            });
          }
        })
    });
    </script>
```

So, how am I supposed to achieve this ?
I searched similar threads and read the doc in the official site but couldn't find a way to start. I think that somehow the results returned from the first call should be appended to DOM with anchor links, this code should be placed to the select property if I am not mistaken. But, I am very new to jquery and these web stuff and can't figure out the way.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can concatenate the results into one. That would be much easier for you.

Comment: I think that's not an optimal solution as I would have to return so much data from the search. Say, I am looking for "Mik". Then I should return all the available information stored in the db from all rows containing "Mik". And that's not good as I am thinking of it for a mobile application too. So, the amount of the transferred data should be as less as possible. Are you suggesting this or haven't I understand your point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how much extra data you need returned.

If it's not much, then it makes sense to return the data as extra properties in a list of objects you are returning for the autocomplete results.

If you think you need too much extra data to make that viable, then in the autocomplete's select callback, you can just use the ID value to fetch all the additional info in an additional AJAX call to a second web service that returns the persons details for the passed in ID value.

Comment: Hi, I decided to actually use a second AJAX call to retrieve the extra information for the person. Thank you for your interest!